# Ошибка в свойстве класса

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Есть два компьютера: на винде и на дебиане, на обоих стоит 15 нода. Так же имеется класс:

```
class User {
    front_id;
    email;
    username;
    password;
    registration_date = null;
    role;
    sessions = [];
    is_confirmed;
    is_blocked;

    constructor() {
    }
}


module.exports = User;
```

На винде всё запускается и работает, на линуксе выскакивает ошибка `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` и указывает именно на `front_id;`

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start:prod": "node src/index.js",
        "start:dev": "node --trace-deprecation --inspect src/index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "argon2": "^0.26.2",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "ip": "^1.1.5",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.14",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "uuid": "^8.1.0"
    }
}
```

Есть какие-нибудь способы фикса, кроме, как перенести свойства в конструктор или использование бабеля?

Comment: не думаю, что проблема именно в этом коде. если вынести ваше объявление класса в отдельный файл и подключить в другом, создать экземпляр - всё работает. или на вашем `linux стоит nodejs по-старше` (возможно на вашем пользователе стоит nvm и это не видно, но запуск кем-то другим использует более старую ноду), или проблема в другом участке кода

Comment: Это ну никак не ES6.

Comment: @nörbörnën, а сможешь дописать код таким образом, чтобы из-за другого кода получить _такую_ ошибку? Кроме throw с фиктивной ошибкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто обнови nodejs хотя бы до 12й версии.

https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields-public-instance-class-fields

[image: скриншот поддержки]

Comment: Проблема оказалась в WebStorm, которая использовала 10 ноду, вместо запущенной в nvm 15 ноды

Comment: ещё можно порекомендовать в `package.json` прописать https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#engines с nodejs >= 12

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
class User {
  constructor() {
    this.front_id;
    this.email;
    this.username;
    this.password;
    this.registration_date = null;
    this.role;
    this.sessions = [];
    this.is_confirmed;
    this.is_blocked;
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

и где нить

```
const User = require('./user');
const user = new User();

console.log(user);
```